# Needs Angularjs support activating in PHPStorm?

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm

I have PHPStorm installed with the Angularjs plugin.
Unfortunately, I still don't get any autocomplete. The IDE still doesn't know about angular.module or others.

Do I need to activate the Angularjs support per project or were could the problem lie?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both `JavaScript Support Plugin` and `Nodejs Plugin` enabled and installed.